# facebook SDK error in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I followed the tutorial exactly as is in the developers.facebook.com but when I press login I get a SIGABRT error. The debugger shows:

```
[SixthViewController login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8476230
2012-08-19 15:56:35.710 pyxida3[21363:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SixthViewController login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8476230'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x256c022 0x1c7fcd6 0x256dcbd 0x24d2ed0 0x24d2cb2 0x256de99 0xde514e 0xde50e6 0xe8bade 0xe8bfa7 0xe8b266 0xe0a3c0 0xe0a5e6 0xdf0dc4 0xde4634 0x1f46ef5 0x2540195 0x24a4ff2 0x24a38da 0x24a2d84 0x24a2c9b 0x1f457d8 0x1f4588a 0xde2626 0x280d 0x2775)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

this is the method called

```
- (IBAction)authButtonAction:(id)sender {
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
// The user has initiated a login, so call the openSession method
// and show the login UX if necessary.
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: With the advent of the most recent version of the facebook SDK, many of their older tutorials and some sample code stopped working.

Comment: Are you sure, that the login is a static class method?SixthViewController is a class or object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you are calling login on your SixthViewController somewhere, and this method is not defined on that viewController class.
Please check where in your code you are doing the login call. You are probably expecting another instance there(maybe your app delegate on which you defined a login method?), but in reality, the instance points to a SixthViewController instance.

Like OhhMee posted, a code snippet showing the login call could shed more clarity.

Comment: i use this tut.. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/ i reached the end of part 4 and when i run and press the button specified i get that error. the only thing i changed was AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    for     AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; because it was not recognized .. i'm new to xcode so any detailed explanation would be appreciated..

Comment: There is no login method in that tutorial.
Might it be possible that you used to have a login method with an IBAction return type, linked it in your xib to the button(that is now the facebook login button), and that you then removed it?
In that case, you would still need to remove the link with this method in your SixthViewController xib.

Comment: ok.. i solved it.. you were right.. there was something wrong with the connection of my buttons in my nib file..!